# Проблемы с установкой Airflow

Tags: ubuntu, cmd, airflow

Установил докер, убунту установилась вместе с ней. Успешно клонирую данные с *git lab*. На этапе установки *airflow* получаю ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я пробовал дословно:

```
sudo apt-get update   
sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends          git          unzip          gnupg          libaio1          libaio-dev          krb5-config          krb5-user          libkrb5-dev   && 
sudo apt-get autoremove -yqq --purge   
sudo apt-get clean   
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Не так много опыта взаимодействия с убунту, подскажите в чем может быть дело?

Comment: Ну у тебя зачем-то добавлена репа майков. Или закаменть или поправь согласно оф. ману.

Comment: Что такое репа майков?)

Comment: Майки - microsoft. Посмотри свой же скрин.

Comment: Подскажи, как это удалить?

Comment: Ну закаменть строки с репами, Ключ gpg можешь оставить, он не влияет.